# How to change the record type of existing opportunities to another record type?

Tags: batch, opportunity, record-type, pricebook, data-migration

There are around 800 opportunities for which I want to change the record type of that opportunities.

These 800 opportunities  are related to different product books. when I change the opportunities record type, the product books are not getting associated with that record type. I have to assign product books  manually based on the old record type.

**It is fine if we have less number of records. How to achieve this for 800 opportunities which is related to different product books.**

Comment: Do you mean price books not product books? Can you map the price book to the opportunity record type as that would mean you could use the bulk api to update using data loader?

Comment: Create 2 reports of Opportunity & products seperately . Include the required fields in the report while extracting it as csv .  Update the records type Id for these 2 objects & update it to salesforce using data loader